# Schemes locally of finite type

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a field. Does it exist an irreducible and separated $k$-scheme locally of finite type which is not of finite type?

Comment: This is addressed in: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/34620/when-is-an-irreducible-scheme-quasi-compact/34656#34656